# CIFilter filterWithName:keysAndValues: set keysAndValues from NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-image, cifilter

Hi im trying to do something like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *param1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"inputIntensity", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8], nil];
[param1 setObject:file forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone" keysAndValues:param1];
```

Obviously it doesnt work, so, how can a fill keysAndValues from an already existing dictionary?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the simplest construction method (filterWithName:) and fill out the values with `[filter setValue:value forKey:key]` iterating through the keys of the existing dictionary. It will require just few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

U can use dictionary like this:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *param = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8],@"inputIntensity",imageView.image,@"inputImage",nil]

 CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone" keysAndValues:@"inputImage",[param objectForKey:@"inputImage"],@"inputIntensity",[param objectForKey:@"inputIntensity",nil]];
```